# Azure Front Door with SSL - how to set this up for HTTPS traffic to App Service?

Tags: azure, https, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

Azure Font Door nicely gives us free SSL certificates (well - included in the price). These are auto-generated and no management is needed.

How can we then achieve SSL communciation to our App service from the Front Door (the Front Door is essentially a reverse proxy)?

The issue is that (as per my understanding) - in order for cookies to work correctly - we must set the Host Header correctly for the traffic going Front Door -> App service - which means that the App Service itself must have the certificate in order to do HTTPS for that host name.... but how can we get the App Service to use the certificate that's in the Front Door?

step by step:

- in browser: https://www.mycompany.com
- this resolves to the Azure Front Door which does the SSL validation.
- Azure Front Door routes this to the App Service hosted on mycompany.azurewebsites.net
- for cookies to work the Front Door must set the Host Header to 'www.mycompany.com'
- in order for this traffic to be HTTPS the App service must have the certificate for 'www.mycompany.com' - but how can I get/use this certificate bearing in mind it's managed by the Front Door?

I can see no way of getting the certificate out of the Front Door.

What am I missing or mis-understanding here please?

thanks-

Comment: I tried using a self signed wildcard cert for securing the App Service back-end, but got an error in the Azure Portal uploading that cert ...

Comment: I was able to do what I needed by using wildcard certs that we happen to have - but the basic question still remains - ...if are using a Front-Door generated cert - is there any way to use that cert to secure the traffic between Front Door and App Service?

Comment: I'd love to know that too. Have you been able to find a better way since then?

Comment: No - we're using separate wildcard certs that are costing us $$$